# Tablet layout, use portrait fragment instead of landscape layout

Tags: java, android, layout, fragment

i am currently designing a tablet layout for my music application.

The handset version has two different layouts for the music player fragment, one for portrait and one for landscape.
I have another fragement which shows the songs in the current playlist.

For the tablet landscape layout, i want to show the portrait player layout and the playlist.

This is the resource for the tablet layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/background"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment android:name="de.qspool.clementineremote.ui.fragments.PlayerFragment"
          android:id="@+id/playerFragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/playlistSongsFragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is, that android shows the landscape layout for the fragment "playerFragment". How can i force him to show the portrait version?

Thanks in advance.

Greetings,
Asfaloth

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can force any activity to show in landscape or portrait from AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name="youractivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
```

Comment: I don't want to force landscape orientation for the whole activity, just for one fragment.